How to use Socks5 on a browser?
I have an Ubuntu virtual server and I want to proxy my browser using extensions like Proxy SwitchyOmega or FoxyProxy. using the following command:
ssh -D 32145 root@ip

I ssh to the server and set the extension settings to the ssh port(32145) and set the server to localhost and socks5 , but it still doesn't work for me.
